# how to extract URI with sparql query

Tags: sparql

I need to extract the URIs of a specific resource from DBpedia. 
Example, my specific resource is "France", I extracted its label but I don't know how to get its URI.
Here is my query so far :

```
    SELECT  ?label 
    WHERE{
    res:France rdfs:label ?label .
    FILTER (lang(?label) = 'fr') .}
```

Thanks for your help !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to filter your resource to be able to extract the URI. Try this:

```
SELECT  distinct *
   WHERE{
   ?uri rdfs:label ?label
   filter (?uri=res:France && lang(?label) = 'fr')
}
```

Comment: You can also use SPARQL 1.1's `VALUES ?uri { res:France }`.